# How to do something when a panel in card layout is brought up

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

I have an application with card layout which contains many panels forms. I use labels to display the form status in each panel. I want to ensure that whenever a panel is brought up, all labels are cleared, but since in card layout a panel is not recreated each time but just brought up, I can't seem to figure out how. Is there a particular way I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `HierarchyListener` to the panel. The listener will be invoked whenever the panel is made visible in the CardLayout:

```
@Override
public void hierarchyChanged(HierarchyEvent e)
{
    JComponent component = (JComponent)e.getSource();

    if ((HierarchyEvent.SHOWING_CHANGED & e.getChangeFlags()) != 0
    &&  component.isShowing())
    {
        // add your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I have to call it or something because when I just added that and put the code for clearing the labels; nothing happened

Comment: Its a listener, just like any other listener, you have to add the listener to the panel using the addHierachyListener(...) method.